# What's the difference between Cut and Cut to?

Tags: screenwriting

What's the difference between Cut and Cut to and where to put each one?

I know both are put between scenes-sluglines but what is the difference between the usage of the two?

Comment: Why the vote to close as off-topic? [Screenwriting is on-topic here](http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/questions/937/are-questions-about-screenplay-on-topic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never seen CUT on its own in a script before, so I honestly can't imagine where you'd use it...

CUT TO:s are rare in today's scripts. Years ago you'd use them above a new slugline. (Or FADE TO: or DISSOLVE TO: or whatever transition you wanted to use; but these choices are now considered to be the director's prerogative.

The transition would always be in the right hand margin, just above the new slug. So:

```
Piers walks into a bar. It's an iron bar.
                                                                   CUT TO:
INT. ER - DAY

The NURSE swabs his head.
```

Generally they're not used any more. So you'd see

```
Piers walks into a pub. It's an iron pub.

INT. PUB - DAY

The LANDLORD looks dumbfounded; that joke obviously makes no sense to him.
```

The other place that you might want to use one is within a scene if the cut's not obvious from context.

```
The pub EXPLODES.
                                                                   CUT TO:
A hand sticking out from some rubble.
```

And finally, of course, they can be used when your script is over.

```
                                                             CUT TO BLACK.
```